# PNG Image Sprites retains background color

Tags: python, png, pygame

I am using [this sprite](http://spriters-resource.com/ds/dgmnworldds/sheet/48629) for some experiments. I cropped a section of the sheet with GIMP and made the blue background transparent, the result being [this](https://github.com/skytreader/PyGame-Objects/raw/master/sample_sprites/meteormon_clueless.png). However, when I run the codes using this sprite, I still end up with a sprite with a blue background. Same thing happens with other sprites (different sprite sheet, same source, same editing process).

Now, I know that I can set transparent colors using PyGame itself but I'm wondering if that's the only way I can do it? Can't I do it through the image itself? How come PyGame still reads a blue backgorund even after I have cleared it with GIMP?

P.S. SSCE would be `pvz_shooter_test.py` and/or `image_test.py` of the GitHub repo linked.

Comment: Are you sure you use the new version of your sprite? Also, please provide the code where you load the image, and don't make us search your git repository. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mySurface.convert_alpha() (check the [pygame documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.convert_alpha) about it).

Answer (score 0):

Just some more additional details on how come PyGame still read a blue background even after I've cleared it with GIMP.

When the image file format supports it, pixels aren't just represented as RGB bits. There's additional information for every pixel, the *alpha* channel. What GIMP did is to set the alpha bits to 0% opacity. The RGB values remained (in this instance, blue). Since my PyGame code isn't set to read the additional alpha bits, it only read the RGB describing blue. The `convert_alpha` method told PyGame to read the alpha channel as well.